# Servlet request.getSession returns null

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I had deployed a webapp on tomcat9 on ec2 instance. using nginx i am doing reverseproxy. The nginx config is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ip_address:8080/webapp;
        proxy_set_header Host www.mydomain.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Now when accessing my application using ww.mydomain.com it opens as expected but at backend when servlets are called let's say xhr.post("POST","profile",true); is done, than calls servlet which checks if session exists or not, but i get null in return. I have this code working in localhost, also if i use http://ip_address:8080/; instead http://ip_address:8080/; as proxy than [www.mydomain.com/webapp](http://www.mydomain.com/webapp) works as expected and also i get session object. but i don't want webapp context path.
What is the issue help me resolve it? why am i getting session null?

I tried [www.mydomain.com/webapp](http://www.mydomain.com/webapp) (it works but has context path in url), I tried change servlet mappings(didn't worked).